# is there a working option that can pick lowest number(s) for my case?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently having problem with picking lowest percent score (or scores if there are similar ones) and lay it out with 5 columns. The two options I tried to give me errors and I'm not sure if my layout is just wrong or i need to group them differently!

So far I've tried picking a lowest number by just using "min" which still listed all of the percent scores (instead of picking lowest) and using "asc" option which gave me an error.

One option:

```
    select name, minor, [Course Name], [Courses Taken t].Department, [percent score] , GPA
    from [Student Information t], [Courses Taken t], [Courses t]
    where name like 'Insert Name' 
    and [Student Information t].studentID=[Courses Taken t].studentID 
    and [Student Information t].Minor is not null
    group by [Percent Score] order [Percent Score] ASC limit 1
```

Result:

```
Error: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near 'Percent Score'.
```

Another Option:

```
select name, minor, [Course Name], [Courses Taken t].Department, min([percent score]) as [percent score], GPA
from [Student Information t], [Courses Taken t], [Courses t]
where name like 'Insert Name' 
and [Student Information t].studentID=[Courses Taken t].studentID 
and [Student Information t].Minor is not null
group by name, minor, [Course Name], [Courses Taken t].Department, GPA
```

```
Result: listed all percent scores (instead of the lowest)
```

I want results to give me the lowest number. In this case, there are two numbers that are the same so I would like them both listed, but I am not sure what I am doing wrong! Any hints would be appreciated <3

Comment: `order by` not just order

Comment: YOu should really stop using the ANSI-89 JOIN syntax. It was replaced by the ANSI-92 JOIN syntax some 27 years ago. [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: LIMIT is mysql syntax but this is tagged with sql server.

Comment: Also, there's no reason to use `LIKE`. As your literal string has no wildcards, you're better off using `{Table Alias}.[name] = 'Insert Name'`

Comment: @SeanLange yes, I removed the MySQL tag, as the error message is clearly SQL Server (I hadn't noticed the `LIMIT`, but that doesn't change that the RDBMS here is clear).

Comment: Bottom line this is a hot mess of mixed up syntax, missing words, old coding style, incorrect usage of keywords....so many things gone wrong in so little code.

Comment: Starting to just learn mysql and receiving many good advices! thank you guys. Will work on my mess and triple check it next time. Need to hop back to more reading for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My *guess* is the query you want is this, however, it has a few comments in it:

```
SELECT TOP 1
       SI.[name], --Guessed table
       SI.minor, --Guessed table
       CT.Department,
       C.[percent score], --Guessed table
       C.GPA --Guessed tables
FROM [Student Information t] SI
     JOIN [Courses Taken t] CT ON SI.studentID = CT.studentID
     CROSS JOIN [Courses t] C --Should this be a CROSS JOIN? You had no implicit JOIN in your WHERE
WHERE SI.[name] = 'Insert Name'
--Removed GROUP BY, this query has no aggregation
ORDER BY C.[percent score]; --ORDER BY, not ORDER
```

This is basically how you should have written your first query. Hopefully, even if this doesn't give you the result set you're after, it gets you close enough.

Comment: Excellent guesswork here. I think we have a winner.

Comment: That is pretty much spot on. My only question is if there are two/three (lowest) numbers that are identical, how can i display them all?

Comment: Change `TOP 1` to `TOP 1 WITH TIES` maybe @TimS ? Hard to tell without sample data and expected results.

Comment: @TimS Please consider &amp;quot;Accepting&amp;quot; as Answer by clicking the checkmark next to this post. It helps the &quot;Questions&quot; Queue, contributors looking to provide answers, Lamu, future visitors to this page, and will even give you a few points. Contributors are motivated by reputation Thanks.

Comment: Oops, I guess I meant to @ TSNA. The mobile layout is different, and more difficult to identify the authors. Also, comment window is tiny, cannot be navigated to proofread or edit, and misreads some characters. sigh. Anyway,  Welcome to SO, @TSNA! Glad you found the answers you needed.